# JSP y Servlet consistencia

Tags: netbeans, jsp, jpa, glassfish

estoy haciendo una red social pequeña para un proyecto y tengo el siguiente error/duda:

Tenemos Usuarios y Amistades, donde al darle a un boton "Añadir amigo" se crea una entidad Amistad ligada al usuario que manda la solicitud y el que la recibe. Este el parte del modelo ER:

[image]

Cuyas clases JPA son:

```
`@Entity
@Table(name = "usuario")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Usuario.findAll", query = "SELECT u FROM Usuario u")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Usuario.findByIdUsuario", query = "SELECT u FROM Usuario u WHERE u.idUsuario = :idUsuario")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Usuario.findByNick", query = "SELECT u FROM Usuario u WHERE u.nick = :nick")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Usuario.findByNombre", query = "SELECT u FROM Usuario u WHERE u.nombre = :nombre")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Usuario.findByApellidos", query = "SELECT u FROM Usuario u WHERE u.apellidos = :apellidos")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Usuario.findByEmail", query = "SELECT u FROM Usuario u WHERE u.email = :email")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Usuario.findByPassword", query = "SELECT u FROM Usuario u WHERE u.password = :password")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Usuario.findBySexo", query = "SELECT u FROM Usuario u WHERE u.sexo = :sexo")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Usuario.findByEdad", query = "SELECT u FROM Usuario u WHERE u.edad = :edad")})
```

```
 public class Usuario implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "idUsuario")
private Integer idUsuario;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 45)
@Column(name = "nick")
private String nick;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 45)
@Column(name = "nombre")
private String nombre;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 45)
@Column(name = "apellidos")
private String apellidos;
// @Pattern(regexp="[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?", message="Invalid email")//if the field contains email address consider using this annotation to enforce field validation
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 45)
@Column(name = "email")
private String email;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 45)
@Column(name = "password")
private String password;
@Size(max = 1)
@Column(name = "sexo")
private String sexo;
@Column(name = "edad")
private Integer edad;
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "usuarioList")
private List<Chat> chatList;
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "usuarioCreador")
private List<Chat> chatList1;
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "amigoID")
private List<Amistad> amistadList;
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "idUsuario")
private List<Mensaje> mensajeList;`
```

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "amistad")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Amistad.findAll", query = "SELECT a FROM Amistad a")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Amistad.findByIdSolicitud", query = "SELECT a FROM Amistad a WHERE a.idSolicitud = :idSolicitud")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Amistad.findByConfirmado", query = "SELECT a FROM Amistad a WHERE a.confirmado = :confirmado")})
```

```
public class Amistad implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "idSolicitud")
private Integer idSolicitud;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "confirmado")
private short confirmado;
@JoinColumn(name = "AmigoID", referencedColumnName = "idUsuario")
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private Usuario amigoID;
```

La cosa es que al intentar crear una amistad entre los usuarios u1 y u2 me sale el siguiente error:

**Código:**

```
   protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, 
      HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    Usuario u1 = usuarioFacade.find(3);
    Usuario u2 = usuarioFacade.find(4);

    //Para usuario que envia

    List<Amistad> listaAmistad = u1.getAmistadList();

    Amistad a1 = new Amistad();
    a1.setAmigoID(u2);

    listaAmistad.add(a1);
    u1.setAmistadList(listaAmistad);

    amistadFacade.create(a1);
    usuarioFacade.edit(u1);

    /*
    //Para usuario que envia

    List<Amistad> listaAmistad2 = u1.getAmistadList();

    Amistad a2 = new Amistad();
    a2.setAmigoID(u1);

    listaAmistad2.add(a1);
    u1.setAmistadList(listaAmistad2);

    amistadFacade.create(a2);
    usuarioFacade.edit(u1);
    */
    RequestDispatcher rd = this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");
    rd.forward(request, response);
}`
```

**Error**

```
Advertencia:   StandardWrapperValve[PruebasServlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet PruebasServlet threw exception
javax.ejb.EJBException
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.processSystemException(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:752)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.completeNewTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:702)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.postInvokeTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:507)
    at 
...
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
**Caused by: javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Bean Validation constraint(s) violated while executing Automatic Bean Validation on callback event:'prePersist'. Please refer to embedded ConstraintViolations for details.**
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.listeners.BeanValidationListener.validateOnCallbackEvent(BeanValidationListener.java:108)
    ...
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4758)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4746)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
    ... 35 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues en tu definición

```
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "confirmado")
private short confirmado;
```

esa columna es no nula y no la estás inicializando al crear la amistad.

```
Amistad a1 = new Amistad();
a1.setAmigoID(u2);

listaAmistad.add(a1);
u1.setAmistadList(listaAmistad);

amistadFacade.create(a1);
usuarioFacade.edit(u1);
```

Podrías probar algo parecido a

```
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "confirmado")
private short confirmado = 0;
```

para que tenga un valor por defecto y no falle al validar la nueva instancia. Aunque yo usaría booleanos si voy a hacer algo que funciona como booleano.

Comment: Si, era eso, que al no tener la columna autoincremental y no darle un valor me decia que no podia insertar el elemento sin la PK. Gracias.

Comment: Con gusto. Si esta respuesta te sirvió, márcala como aceptada